# Six digit numbers with at least one digit even

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Given the following problem:

> How many six digit numbers have at least one even digit?

*I have tried the following:*

The total possible number of variations for six digits knowing that the first digit cannot be a zero, would be: $$9 \cdot 9^6 = 9 \cdot 531441 = 4782969$$

And knowig that all odd numbers are of the set $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$ which is a total of: $$5^6 = 15625$$.

Then my final answer would be: $$4782969-15625 = 4767344$$

Would this be a correct approach to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the approach is correct but there seems to be some calculation mistake. Total $6$ digit numbers are $9*10^5=900000$.

Now we subtract those cases in which there are only odd digits.

Hence the number of such numbers are $5^6=15625$.

Hence the final answer would be 
$$900000-15625 = 884375$$

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is good only mistake is that you have $9*10^5$ in total 6 digits numbers